# How to find the Cp, difference of Cp and heat of fusion from the dependence of vapor pressure on temperature?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, enthalpy, phase, vapor-pressure

> The vapor pressure of zinc varies with temperature as
>
> $$\log P(\pu{mm Hg}) = -6850/T - 0.755\log T + 11.24 \label{eqn:1}\tag{1}$$
>
> and that of liquid zinc as
>
> $$\log P(\pu{mm Hg}) = -6620/T - 1.255\log T + 12.34 \label{eqn:2}\tag{2}$$
>
> Calculate:
>
> a) boiling point of $\ce{Zn};$
> b) triple point;
> c) heat of evaporation at boiling point;
> d) heat of fusion;
> e) the difference in $C_p$ of solid and liquid zinc.

I have found out the boiling point by substituting pressure as $\pu{760 mm Hg}$ on first equation \eqref{eqn:1}, from here boiling point $T$ can be found out as $\pu{1181 K}.$

I have also found out triple point by equating the two equations because at triple point both the pressure of the two phases must be equal.

I have also found out heat of vaporization by using the equation

$$\frac{\mathrm d\ln p}{\mathrm dT} = \frac{H_\mathrm{vap}}{RT^2}.$$

But to find the heat of fusion I must know the heat of sublimation, but the heat of sublimation is not provided here. Is there any other way to know the heat of fusion (melting)?

Also, how to find the $C_p$ of both the phases and the difference of $C_p?$

Answer (score 1):

Use the equation for the vapor pressure of the solid to get the heat of sublimation.  The heat capacity of the vapor minus the heat capacity of the liquid is equal to the derivative of the heat of vaporization with respect to temperature. The heat capacity of the vapor minus the heat capacity of the solid is equal to the derivative of the heat of sublimation with respect to temperature.

ADDENDUM

$$\Delta H_{sublimation}=RT^2\frac{d\ln{P}}{dT}=(\ln{10})RT^2\frac{d\log{P}}{dT}$$where log P is given by Eqn. 1.

Comment: But here vapor pressure of solid zinc is not provided, no equation for solid Zinc,  only for liquid zinc there is an equation, heat  capacity of vapor and liquid is also not provided, heat capacity of solid zinc is also not given , all are unknown , impossible to find out

Comment: When they used the words "The vapor pressure of zinc varies...," what phase did you think they meant?

Comment: If it is of solid then , we must know the sublimation Temperature and Pressure , only then we can find heat of sublimation ,heat capacity of vapor is not given, heat capacity of solid and liquid zinc is also not given,

Comment: Read my answer again.

Comment: In the first lines you said "Use the equation for the vapor pressure of the solid to get the heat of sublimation" but here I don't know neither the pressure of sublimation nor the temperature of sublimation  so both are unknown, if one of them was known we could have put in the equation of solid zinc and find out the other, and hence can calculate Heat of sublimation.

Comment: The heat of sublimation is a function of temperature, obtained in the analogous  way that you got the heat of vaporization as a function of temperature.

Comment: Yeah but for that also Pressure or temperature is required

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98967/discussion-between-sayantan-bhanja-and-chet-miller).

Comment: BTW the question is regarding the heat of *fusion* but for some reason the conversation here is only about sublimation (I suppose sublimation and vaporization enthalpies combined approximate that of fusion).

Comment: @BuckThorn. It follows from Hess' law that, at the triple point, the heat of fusion is equal to the heat of vaporization minus the heat of sublimation.

Comment: Actually, the heat of fusion is equal to the heat of sublimation minus the heat of vaporization.